# Change Kontakt SDK time frame for updating beacon distance

Tags: android, sdk, ibeacon-android, kontakt.io

I've been trying to use Kontakt.io's sample Android app to implement a simple app that would connect to a **Kontakt** beacon and show the beacon details. Now what i noticed is that the beacons are updating very slow i.e. after almost **2 seconds**, however i want it to update after some **400 or 500 milliseconds** so that when a beacon device is move here and there then the android screen should show that distance in more fast way. Following is the code from the Scan Activity.Here I am getting the majors of beacons and their distances from the phone. And on update I am updating the first index i.e. the first beacon detected and getting its distance but it is updating so slow

```
private IBeaconListener createIBeaconListener() {
return new IBeaconListener() {
  @Override
  public void onIBeaconDiscovered(IBeaconDevice iBeacon, IBeaconRegion region) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onIBeaconDiscovered: " + iBeacon.getMajor() + " " + iBeacon.getDistance());
  }

  @Override
  public void onIBeaconsUpdated(List<IBeaconDevice> iBeacons, IBeaconRegion region) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onIBeaconsUpdated: " + iBeacons.get(0).getDistance());

  }

  @Override
  public void onIBeaconLost(IBeaconDevice iBeacon, IBeaconRegion region) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onIBeaconLost: " + iBeacon.toString());
  }
};
```

I don't know where to change or where to see that after what time the beacon is updating. Anyone knows it?

Answer (score 0):

You can change transmission interval of beacons in kontakt beacon dashboard. but if you are changing too much it causes major issues with signal stability. [see here](https://support.kontakt.io/hc/en-gb/articles/201567802-Advertising-Interval-best-practise).

if you want to update 400 or 500 milliseconds, you can change transmission power accordingly.